# How to properly release resources in RxJava2?

Tags: java, selenium, rx-java2

I am writing a scraper in Java using Selenium with ChromeDriver and I want to wrap it into Observable (for easier async). This is the code that returns Observable from my parser class:

```
return Observable.interval(5000, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .doOnSubscribe(ignored -> initialize())
                .doOnNext(ignored -> refreshPage())
                .map(ignored -> getHtml())
                .map(this::parse)
                .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .doFinally(() -> finish())
                .share();
```

So here, `initialize()` basically creates a configure instance of Selenium WebDriver, `refreshPage()` reloads the page and waits for it to load, `getHtml()` is just `driver.getPageSource()` and `finish()` is `driver.quit()` where `driver` is an instance of Selenium WebDriver. The problem that I have is when I subscribe to this Observable and later dispose it. I get an exception from `refreshPage()` that says that I called a method on `driver` after `driver.quit()` (or in the code above that means `refreshPage()` was called after `finish()`).

How should I create/modify my source Observable so that my resource is released properly on disposal? (I want `finish()` to always be called after everything else in the Observable chain has finished).

UPDATE:
My `finish()` function is:

```
public void finish() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`doFinally` does as you suspect. it executes the associated `Action` after:

- `onError`,
- `onComplete`, or
- the associated downstream cancels/disposes the stream

however, what i suspect *may* be happening is you may be invoking `driver.quit()` in the body of `finish()`, rather than in the `Action` it returns. assuming that `driver` is used within `refreshPage()`, the error makes sense since the actual invocation of `doFinally()` itself (not the `Action` it returns) is done early to build the stream behavior, and `refreshPage()` is the earliest point in the stream thereafter that `driver` is used.

if your code looks something like this:

```
private Action finish() {
    driver.quit();

    return () -> {
        ...
    };
}
```

...then move the call to `quit()` to within the body of the `Action`, like:

```
private Action finish() {
    return () -> {
        driver.quit();
    };
}
```

if my assumptions are wrong, can you update the question with the code for `finish()`? i'd be curious to see what's going on there.

Comment: I updated my question, see above. In the original question I made a typo (updated). I have `doFinally(() -> finish())` and not `doFinally(finish())`. Still, this gives me the same error. I also tried creating the observable with Observable.using and had the same behaviour.